# How to perform an accuracy assessment in eCognition?

Tags: remote-sensing, digital-image-processing, accuracy, ecognition

How to do accuracy assessment of classified images in ecognition?

I have done the image segmentation for Worldview-2 image. Then, I have processed for classification for class names (e.g road,building,settlement,barren land) using Nearest Neighborhood.

How can I generate accuracy assessment using TTA mask using eCognition?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, in order to get a helpful answer to your question please provide more information about what you have tried so far and be as specific as possible about your problem.

Comment: I have done the image segmentation for Worldview-2 image. Then, I have processed for classification for class names (e.g road,building,settlement,barren land)using Nearest Neighborhood.

How can I generate accuracy assessment using TTA mask using eCognition?

Answer (score 5):

I would follow as below in version 9:

Use **sample selection** algorithm(use brush and set class) and select samples and save these layer as TTA mask

[image: sample selection]

Then you can generate TTA mask from sample

[image: TTA]

Now you can perform AC.

Comment: Actually first i did segmentation process then collected the proper samples from the classes, then classify the original image using nearest neighbour classification. will you please help me then how to go for accuracy assessment ?

Comment: @Manas see added images.

Comment: Stupid question, I accidentally select wrong segment using brush, how I undo it? I cannot find undo button, nor ctrrl-z also not work.

Comment: @monruw Unfortunately there is no undo in this case- workaround is use this very sample selection tool (using brush) to select the error samples and assign to unclassified or right classes. There are save current project state for restoring and undo process editing that might help in other cases..

Answer (score 1):

After you select the samples and created them to TTA Mask as shown by Slslam, go to Tools->Accuracy Assessment. Select the Level that you want for accuracy assessment then select the statistic type as Error matrix based on TTA Mask.