# How to perform accuracy assessment in eCognition?

Tags: remote-sensing, digital-image-processing, accuracy, ecognition

I have already done the classification using Nearest neighbourhood, and how do I continue to complete AC with TAA?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate - [How to perform an accuracy assessment in eCognition?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143708/how-to-perform-an-accuracy-assessment-in-ecognition)